# Decorating vertices with multiple attributes

Tags: r, networking

In `igraph` I have a network and decorate the vertices with two attributes, agent type (vertex color: green & blue) and agent size (vertex size by rank).  I would like to add a centrality measure as a third attribute.  While I can play with vertex shape, I prefer an approach that literally decorates an existing vertex rather than change its characteristic, like its shape. I haven't found many 3-attribute examples on the internet.  Any suggestions for a clean representation of a network with 3-attribute vertices?

Comment: I guess you could do agent type as the shape, agent size as the vertex size, and centrality as a color gradient?

Comment: There's fill color and boundary color on the vertex you can adjust.